# Getting Null Value joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is the Query,I had joined 3 tables supplier is main table. The actual scenario is I want all the data from table account payable table though it is not their in purchase order table, so I have joined using FULL Outer with supplier and Purchase Order, but the supplier details were not coming against the data of account payable though supplier key is available.

```
SELECT ISNULL(dbo.Supplier.supplier_key,dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.supplier_key) AS supplier_key,
                  dbo.Supplier.Supplier,
                  dbo.Supplier.Name,
                  dbo.Supplier.Status, 
                  dbo.Supplier.AddressCode, 
                  dbo.Supplier.Address,
                  dbo.Supplier.HouseNo,
                  dbo.Supplier.Street,
                  dbo.Supplier.City, 
                  dbo.Supplier.Country,
                  dbo.Supplier.ZipCode,
                  dbo.Supplier.StartDate,
                  dbo.Supplier.CreditLimit, 
                  dbo.Supplier.FinancialGroup,
                  dbo.Supplier.LastTransactionDate, 
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.Company, 
                  ISNULL(dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Purchase Order],dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[PO Number]) AS PurchaseOrder,
                  ISNULL( dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.Sequence,dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.Line) AS POSequence, 
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Order Quantity], 
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Per Purchase Unit], 
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Per Quantity Price],
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Purchase price unit],
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Total Order Amount],
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.Currency, 
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Rate Date], 
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Actual Receipt Date],
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Receipt No],
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Receipt Sequence], 
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Received Quantity],
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Approved Quantity], 
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Purchase Office], 
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Invoice Number], 
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Invoice Date], 
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Invoice Quantity],
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Invoice Amount],
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.InvoiceNumber, 
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.Type AS InvoiceType, 
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[Order Type] AS OrderInvoiceType,
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.AP_Balance_EUR, 
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[Invoice Amount_EUR],
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.supplier_key AS EXPR2,
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[IntercompanyTrade Order No] AS EXPR23, 
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[IntercompanyTrade Line Number] AS EXPR24,
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[Intercompany Trade Financial Company] AS EXPR25, 
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[Intercompany Trade Purchase Company] AS EXPR26,
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.InvoiceNumber,
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.DueDate,
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.DocDate, 
                  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Order Date],
                  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[Invoice Amount_EUR],
                  (CASE WHEN dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Receipt No] = ' ' THEN dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Total Order Amount]
                        WHEN  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Receipt No] != ' ' and dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.InvoiceNumber IS NULL then dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Total Order Amount] END) AS ORDERBALANCE,
                  (dbo.Supplier.CreditLimit -(ORDERBALANCE + dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[Invoice Amount_EUR])) AS Availablecredit
    FROM            dbo.Supplier 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder ON dbo.Supplier.supplier_key = dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.buyfrom_supplier_key
            full OUTER JOIN dbo.Fact_AccountPayables ON dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.supplier_key = dbo.Supplier.supplier_key AND
                                                        dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[PO Number] = dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Purchase Order]   AND 
                                                    dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[PO Line] = dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.Sequence
```

The output is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have used not only supplier key, but also PO number and PO line as join criterion with full outer join. If there is no  matching entry for these (matching entries for ALL join criteria in the same time) in supplier table you will also see the null values you mentioned.

Just for testing remove temporarily the other join criteria (PO number and line) and leave only the supplier key. Check if you still see the null values in this case.

Comment: I have tried that but if I join only with supplier key I am getting duplicate records.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement then: what should happen in case if there is no matching entry in supplier table for all your join criteria?

Comment: @MátéGábor Pretty easy. There are only two choices here: either include them with NULL values (as is currently done) or leave them away (using a LEFT join instead of a FULL join). This choice is up to the OP.

Comment: @MateGabor ,without entering the supplier no one can book purchase order or do any payment in Account Payable,Its like supplier is mandatory,And My requirement is very simple I want all the Purchase order booked for a supplier and the payment details of the specific supplier.

Comment: Scenario 1) It not necessary that all purchase order booked are paid  i'e Purchase order table contain data and Account Payable don't.  Scenario 2) It is not necessary that advance payment done have purchase order if supplier is top rated the advance cheque is provided without booking Purchase order or have Purchase requistion. I.e Purchase table dnt have data and Account Payable table have.Hope you understood

Comment: @user3526183: you didn't answer my question. I suggest that you answer that question (for yourself). Then you can decide which join type and criteria you need. Also I suggest that you stay at one scenario first. Maybe you should read about the meaning of different joins if you find it difficult answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try your Payable table after that **FROM** Clause and join the other tables by using **LEFT JOIN**

```
FROM dbo.Fact_AccountPayables         
LEFT JOIN dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder ON  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[PO Number] =  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Purchase Order]   AND 
 dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[PO Line] =  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.Sequence
LRFT JOIN dbo.Supplier  ON dbo.Supplier.supplier_key = dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.buyfrom_supplier_key AND dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.supplier_key = dbo.Supplier.supplier_key
```

Comment: If I take Fact_AccountPayables as main table then it will not take all the suppliers,I want all the suppliers whether they have Purchase order,done Account payable or not. That's the reason I need to take dbo.supplier as main table.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a FULL join for the Fact_AccountPayables table. This way, all records from Fact_AccountPayables are included even if there are no matches with the other two tables. If you don't want that, use LEFT join instead of FULL join.

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(dbo.Supplier.supplier_key, dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.supplier_key) AS supplier_key,
  dbo.Supplier.Supplier,
  dbo.Supplier.Name,
  dbo.Supplier.Status, 
  dbo.Supplier.AddressCode, 
  dbo.Supplier.Address,
  dbo.Supplier.HouseNo,
  dbo.Supplier.Street,
  dbo.Supplier.City, 
  dbo.Supplier.Country,
  dbo.Supplier.ZipCode,
  dbo.Supplier.StartDate,
  dbo.Supplier.CreditLimit, 
  dbo.Supplier.FinancialGroup,
  dbo.Supplier.LastTransactionDate, 
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.Company, 
  ISNULL(dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Purchase Order], dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[PO Number]) AS PurchaseOrder,
  ISNULL(dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.Sequence, dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.Line) AS POSequence,
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Order Quantity], 
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Per Purchase Unit], 
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Per Quantity Price],
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Purchase price unit],
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Total Order Amount],
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.Currency, 
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Rate Date], 
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Actual Receipt Date],
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Receipt No],
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Receipt Sequence], 
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Received Quantity],
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Approved Quantity], 
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Purchase Office], 
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Invoice Number], 
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Invoice Date], 
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Invoice Quantity],
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Invoice Amount],
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.InvoiceNumber, 
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.Type AS InvoiceType, 
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[Order Type] AS OrderInvoiceType,
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.AP_Balance_EUR, 
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[Invoice Amount_EUR],
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.supplier_key AS EXPR2,
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[IntercompanyTrade Order No] AS EXPR23, 
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[IntercompanyTrade Line Number] AS EXPR24,
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[Intercompany Trade Financial Company] AS EXPR25, 
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[Intercompany Trade Purchase Company] AS EXPR26,
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.InvoiceNumber,
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.DueDate,
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.DocDate, 
  dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Order Date],
  dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[Invoice Amount_EUR],
  CASE
    WHEN dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Receipt No] = ' ' THEN dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Total Order Amount]
    WHEN dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.InvoiceNumber IS NULL THEN dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Total Order Amount]
  END AS ORDERBALANCE,
  dbo.Supplier.CreditLimit - (ORDERBALANCE + dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[Invoice Amount_EUR]) AS Availablecredit
FROM
  dbo.Supplier 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder ON dbo.Supplier.supplier_key = dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.buyfrom_supplier_key
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Fact_AccountPayables ON
    dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.supplier_key = dbo.Supplier.supplier_key AND
    dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[PO Number] = dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Purchase Order]   AND 
    dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[PO Line] = dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.Sequence
```

Comment: Sorry but left join will not fetch all the data from account payable table.

Comment: That is correct. As far as I can see, there are two possibilities regarding the records in your AccountPayables table. Either you include them all (using FULL join) and settle with NULLs in the columns of the other two tables when there is no match. Or you exclude them if they won't fit to the other two tables (using LEFT join). There is no other choice. What are your expectations? What should be done with data from the AccountPayable table that cannot be matched to data in the other two tables?

Comment: I think I understand your issue, but as I see it, it probably has to do with data integrity. Somehow it seems possible, that your database can contain records in table AccountPayable that do not refer to corresponding existing records in tables Supplier and/or PurchaseOrder. (Perhaps there have been records deleted from the PurchaseOrder and/or the Supplier tables in the past, and the related records in the AccountPayables table have not been deleted as well?)

Comment: So I suggest you take a closer look at those records from the AccountPayables table that cause NULL values for supplier and purchase order data. Temporarily include the field `dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[PO Number]` in your SELECT clause and check if those values still exist in the Fact_PurchaseOrder table, for example. (And if they still exist, check if the supplier keys in both tables still match.)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the rows are getting filtered in the Fact_PurchaseOrder, if they dont have supplier. You need to go for FULL OUTER JOIN for all tables, to get data for all rows of AccountPayables, irrespective of whether they have got suppliers or not.

```sql
FROM  dbo.Supplier 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder ON dbo.Supplier.supplier_key = dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.buyfrom_supplier_key
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Fact_AccountPayables ON dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.supplier_key = dbo.Supplier.supplier_key AND
                                                        dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[PO Number] = dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.[Purchase Order]   AND 
                                                    dbo.Fact_AccountPayables.[PO Line] = dbo.Fact_PurchaseOrder.Sequence
```